# Best way to load thousands of records to a Expandable List View

Tags: android, web-services, expandablelistview

I have an Android App that needs to populate an Expandable List View from a database, the thing is that I need to load like 1700 items to the list. Which is the best way to load the data?

The app crash when I want to search inside the list.

Comment: IMHO, users generally do not want to scroll through 1700 items.

Comment: search the database instead and then show the results in the list and use lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a custom library. [For example, this](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView).
Still I can advise to make a local copy of the database and [this adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644914/android-expandablelistview-and-sqlite-database).
But 1700 is a lot of elements in terms of usability.